# Combine two python with statements that share the same code

Tags: python, python-3.5

```
def test(file_name):
    if file_name.lower().endswith('.gz'):
        with gzip.open(file_name) as f:
            f_csv = csv.reader(i.TextIOWrapper(f))
            #### Same Code

    if file_name.lower().endswith('.csv'):
        with open(file_name) as f:
            f_csv = csv.reader(i.TextIOWrapper(f))
            #### Same Code
```

Question> Is there a better way to combine the above code without duplicating the 'Same Code' section? The function `test` uses gzip.open if the the `file_name` is a gz file otherwise it opens with regular `open`.

Comment: Just put `#### Same Code` into a (local) function? `def same_code(f_csv): ...` Or dispatch the file handler according to the ending by putting it into a dict for example or writing a custom dispatch function. `with custom_open(file_name) as fp: ...`

Comment: You could use *os.path.splitext()* instead of repeating cumbersome *.lower().endswith()*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way would be:

```
def test(file_name):
    loader = None
    if file_name.lower().endswith('.gz'):
        loader = gzip.open
    elif file_name.lower().endswith('.csv'):
        loader = open

    if loader is not None:
        with loader(file_name) as f:
            f_csv = csv.reader(i.TextIOWrapper(f))
            #### Same Code
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def test(file_name):
    f = None
    if file_name.lower().endswith('.gz'):
        f = gzip.open(file_name)

    if file_name.lower().endswith('.csv'):
        f = open(file_name)

    if f is not None:
        f_csv = csv.reader(i.TextIOWrapper(f))
        #### Same Code
        f.close()
```